# pry gem how to reload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I am using the Pry gem in my Rails console, but the pry flavored rails-console seems to have lost the reload! method for reloading models and stuff.

Here's how I start the pry console

```
c:\rails\app> pry -r ./config/environment
```

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check out this page on the Pry wiki: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry

Also check out the `pry-rails` plugin: https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails

There's also a lot of other content on that wiki, it's a great resource.

Comment: pry-rails does not add `reload!`

Answer (score 25):

To use reload! like the rails console command, add this code to your .pryrc

```
# load Rails Console helpers like reload
require 'rails/console/app'
extend Rails::ConsoleMethods
puts 'Rails Console Helpers loaded'
```

EDIT==
Gem pry-rails already do all of this, much simplier .

Answer (score 12):

For anyone coming to this question recently: the answer has changed in Rails 3.2, because they've changed how they implement `reload!`  Where in earlier version the irb commands were added as methods to `Object`, now they are added to `IRB::ExtendCommandBundle` to avoid polluting the global namespace.

What I do now is (1) in development.rb

```
silence_warnings do
  begin
    require 'pry'
    IRB = Pry
    module Pry::RailsCommands ;end
    IRB::ExtendCommandBundle = Pry::RailsCommands
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

and (2) in .pryrc

```
if Kernel.const_defined?("Rails") then
  require File.join(Rails.root,"config","environment")
  require 'rails/console/app'
  require 'rails/console/helpers'
  Pry::RailsCommands.instance_methods.each do |name| 
    Pry::Commands.command name.to_s do 
      Class.new.extend(Pry::RailsCommands).send(name)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the link to the Rails pull request where the change was introduced -
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3509

Answer (score 6):

You could tell Pry to load your Rails environment in your `.pryrc`

```
rails = File.join Dir.getwd, 'config', 'environment.rb'

if File.exist?(rails) && ENV['SKIP_RAILS'].nil?
  require rails

  if Rails.version[0..0] == "2"
    require 'console_app'
    require 'console_with_helpers'
  elsif Rails.version[0..0] == "3"
    require 'rails/console/app'
    require 'rails/console/helpers'
  else
    warn "[WARN] cannot load Rails console commands (Not on Rails2 or Rails3?)"
  end
end
```

This will give your `reload!` back.

Comment: ahhhh, the reload! appears to be working but actually didn't reload any models; however, the plugin from Banister's answer seems to do it

Comment: in Rails 3.2 I also needed to say `include Rails::ConsoleMethods`

Answer (score 3):

If you are having trouble with Zeus and Pry, try adding to your `.pryrc`:

```
if Kernel.const_defined?(:Rails) && Rails.env
  require File.join(Rails.root,"config","environment")
  require 'rails/console/app'
  require 'rails/console/helpers'
  extend Rails::ConsoleMethods
end
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/466)

Answer (score 2):

I've recently written a post about pry and rails. You can find it here http://lucapette.com/pry/pry-everywhere/. By the way, as dave already said, you would like to use pry with:

```
pry -r ./config/environment
```

I recommend you to try what I wrote in the article, it works really fine.

Comment: You can use `RAILS_ENV=production pry -r ./config/environment` for use in the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

```
alias pryr="pry -r ./config/environment -r rails/console/app -r rails/console/helpers"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `./config/environment`?

In any case, I think that's different than actually launching a rails console, which is where `reload!` comes from. I redefine `IRB = Pry` in my env-specific config file, which ensures a full console, and it all works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A better version of @Rodrigo Dias's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800826/4675524).
If you don't want to use `pry-rails` gem then just add following into your `.pryrc`-

```
if defined?(Rails) && Rails.env
  if defined?(Rails::ConsoleMethods)
    include Rails::ConsoleMethods
  else
    def reload!(print=true)
      puts "Reloading..." if print
      ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup!
      ActionDispatch::Reloader.prepare!
      true
    end
  end
end
```

This code properly identifies environments and doesn't blindly includes `Rails::ConsoleMethods`.

Source - Github thread [comment](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails/issues/9#issuecomment-72305084)