# Assigning an exception to a variable in pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

So I'm trying to use pry to debug a method_missing in my Rails app and am getting a:

```
[5] pry(#<VoyageArrival>)> puts e
NameError: undefined local variable or method `e' for #<VoyageArrival:0x007fa3f30d13c8>
```

Here's my code

```
  21: define_method(save_method) do
    22:   if "@#{method_name}".present?
    23:     begin
    24:       self.send("#{attribute}=", Time.parse(instance_variable_get("@#{method_name}")))
    25:     rescue => e
 => 26:       binding.pry
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using?And what gems (pry related) have you included?

Comment: Pry - 0.9.12 - with dependencies -> [coderay ~>1.0.5, method_source ~> 0.8, slop ~> 3.4] and Rails 3.2.11

Comment: Could you provide more information? You mentioned `method_missing`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the last exception via the global variable `$!`. See if that works in your breakpoint. It may be that you have another breakpoint set somewhere, and are actually debugging the wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but try to tell what are you rescuing. For example:

```
rescue Exception => e
```

Let me know if that works to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard a colleague talk about something similar. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348158/326543) (fairly old) answer says use `pry-rails` instead of `pry`. This worked in our case.

More about pry-rails - https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails