# Pry-rails not reloading correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

When I enter `reload!` in my Rails console using `pry-rails`, it doesn't appear to be working; i.e., the changes I made to my code aren't implemented. Everything I've read seems to say that the `pry-rails` gem implements `reload!` all on its own.

Here's how I test it: (I put `Deal.hello` in my code between pry lines 1 & 2)

```rb
// ♥ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 66760
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.2)
[1] pry(main)> Deal.hello                                                                                                                     
NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for Deal (call 'Deal.connection' to establish a connection):Class
from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
[2] pry(main)> Deal.hello                                                                                                                     
NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for Deal (call 'Deal.connection' to establish a connection):Class
from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
[3] pry(main)> reload!                                                                                                                        
Reloading...
=> true
[4] pry(main)> Deal.hello                                                                                                                     
NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for Deal (call 'Deal.connection' to establish a connection):Class
from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
[5] pry(main)> exit                                                                                                                           
[11:50:33] (deal-has-one-region) fares-you-can-use-rails
// ♥ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 66780
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.2)
[1] pry(main)> Deal.hello                                                                                                                     
=> "hello"
[2] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pry gem how to reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347327/pry-gem-how-to-reload)

Comment: Have added a duplicate there ^^ that may help :)

Comment: That post implies that `pry-rails` should take care of it, no?