# Rails RSpec Pry "reload!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, pry-rails

- ruby 2.3.1
- rails (3.2.22.4)
- rspec-rails (2.14.2)
- pry-rails (0.3.2)
- pry-byebug (3.6.0)
- pry (0.10.4)

I am using a bit old version of Ruby and Rails.

I am running RSpec tests in the Ubuntu Terminal:

```
rspec ./spec/features/some_spec.rb
```

and I am using `pry` breakpoints (`binding.pry` - inside my RSpec tests).

I am missing the `reload!` method while debugging the code in these breakpoints (under RSpec only). (I mean dynamically reload the changed model code - like adding new methods on the fly etc.) This method is even not defined there. I do have the `reload!` method defined and working in Rails console - but not in the RSpec debug breakpoint.

How to set up `reload!` in RSpec?

I tried the solutions on [pry gem how to reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347327/pry-gem-how-to-reload) , but neither worked for me.

This one appears to be the closest to the real solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50966785/6594668 , it does actually define `reload!` - but this `reload!` does nothing.

A quick sample:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def foo1
    p 123
  end
end
```

When I run Rails console, change the method name from `foo1` to `foo2`, call `reload!` - then these calls work OK:

```
User.first.foo1
=> 123
#change the method name (by manually editing the file)
User.first.foo2
=> 123
```

But - when I do the same thing in RSpec debug breakpoint - it does not actually reload the code - even if I manually define `reload!` with either of 2 ways:

1.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50966785/6594668

```
def reload!(print=true)
  puts "Reloading..." if print
  ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup!
  ActionDispatch::Reloader.prepare!
  true
end
```

2.
https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails/issues/99#issuecomment-364272642

```
Object.send(:include, Rails::ConsoleMethods)
```

Looks like something I still am missing (for `reload!` to work in RSpec).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just found it.

The only thing I needed to change was this:

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # config.cache_classes = true
  config.cache_classes = false
end
```

Now in RSpec breakpoints I can successfully reload the changed code by calling `reload!` - just exactly the same way as in the Rails console.

Comment: Ah, good to know. So far I was getting by with simply pasting patched class/method definitions into the rspec console. Or re-running the spec.

Comment: Re-running a spec is not a good idea when your test is failing only when running a whole RSpec suite (taking 30 mins or so) - and passes OK being run standalone.

Comment: Yes, I hate this kind of failures with a passion :)

Comment: Now I am thinking about where to put `Object.send(:include, Rails::ConsoleMethods)` as some RSpec initializer. I just don't want to manually call it each time when debugging a spec.

Comment: rails_helper.rb, maybe?